# C# specflow Selenium tests working fine in local (CLI and VS 2017 NUnit Runner). But failing in team city with error Could not find element

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, teamcity, specflow

I am working on building Smoke Tests (3 tests) for our company's web portal, which is built using **C#, N-Unit, Selenium** and **Specflow**.

These smoke tests are working fine in local in Visual Studio N-Unit Runner and Command Line interface (CLI). But, when we run the same tests in TeamCity CI or in CLI from TeamCity Agent server, one or two tests failing with error, such as below.

```
"OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Could not find element by: By.CssSelector: #u_r_v_search_btn"
```

Appropriate web element locators are in place in the test suite and looks good when we run in local. But throwing error when we run the tests in TeamCity CI pipeline.

Below command, which is working fine in local. Same command failing in TeamCity Agent Server when we run it from CLI; With error such as *"could not find element".*

```
 ----> nunit3-console.exe ..\..\..\Tests\Bin\Debug\Tests.dll --noheader --where cat==smoke
```

Team City CI commmand statement from build log:

```
C:\buildAgent\tools\NUnit.Console.3.9.0\nunit3-console.exe C:\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\eahe9vWdDNwsMCnwYM0DJIHv4X7ycBFR.nunit --result=C:\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\eahe9vWdDNwsMCnwYM0DJIHv4X7ycBFR.nunit.xml --noheader --where cat==smoke
```

Can someone please provide insights to resolve this issue?

Comment: Watch it run or take a screenshot on failure... what do you see? Maybe the page isn't loading, who knows... we can't tell from the information you have provided.

Comment: It looks like a timing problem. Are you sure the page is loaded when you use the selector?